# R command to check if table exists in an sql database

Tags: r

I'm using the `sqldf` R library to write to an sql database using the command:

```
dbWriteTable(db, table_id, as.data.frame(table_df))
```

where `db` is the sql database file, `table_id` is the name of the table to be saved in the sql database, and the data.frame corresponding to the `table_id` is `table_df`.

My question is how do I check if a table with a certain `table_id` already exists in the sql database, and if so I'll skip the `dbWriteTable` for that table.

Comment: `dbWriteTable` is not part of the sqldf package.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My best guess is you're using the `DBI` package which *does* have a `dbWriteTable` function (probably you are loading `DBI` via another package; it has an impressive [reverse dependencies list](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/DBI/index.html)). Quickly glancing at its documentation, `DBI` also has the `dbExistsTable` function that does what you want.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you could do is query the database and pass its contents to an object wrapped in a try() call. If the length() of that object is 0 then it does not exist. This will only work if the table has data in it and not an empty shell.